# Ajax calls half working ... file uploaded but javascript not executed

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, upload, callback

I'm sorry for that question but I have a persistent bug and I don't understand at all what's happening ...

I have an ajax upload function that is working fine

```
function startUp(hash) {

    $('#file_up_form').ajaxForm({
                                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", '{{ Session::token() }}' );
                                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Sha-Sha',hash);
                                    //other stuff
                                    },

                                uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                                 //some stuff
                                },

                                complete : function(xhr) {
                                     //some stuff
                                },

                                error : function(xhr) {
                                    //some stuff
                                }

                            });
 }
```

When I call it that way :

```
$("#start_up_button").on('click', function() {

        if(checkFile()){

            startUp('f4274dd2284704f1158b2cecd71666a37ba5b949f97fc521974f98fa3dd0ea706cca7253244e20f2a4c4c694052097c45260edfe679c9e7b56896858a34839cd');
            //getHash();
        }

        else{
            $('#myModalerror').modal('show');
            $("#myModalerror").css("z-index", "1500");
        }
    });
```

Everything works fine.
But when I uncomment the second line and comment the first to call it from :

```
function getHash(){

        input = document.getElementById('fileToUpload');

        file = input.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var shaObj = new jsSHA(reader.result,"BYTES");
            var hash = shaObj.getHash("SHA-512", "HEX");
            console.log(hash);
            startUp(hash);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

   }
```

Nothing work for ajax : the console.log display the correct hash but there are no headers set, and nothing from '//some stuff' works ... But the file is uploaded !! (??) I tried to wrap the call with a

```
setTimeout(function() {
                            startUp(hash);      
                                    }, 200);
```

but Firefox just crash. Any idea ??

thx

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `ajaxForm()` in `$('#file_up_form').ajaxForm({ ... })`  is **not** to trigger an AJAX request.

It is an event binding function. (I've not gone through the API documentation, but probably it binds a form **submit event** to one of its inner library function)

To actually trigger an AJAX request you've to add a `<input type="submit" >` button inside the HTML `<form>`, and just click it. (Library will prevent traditional form submission, and submit it via AJAX)

**Example implementation:**

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#file_up_form").ajaxForm({ // bind library function to the form
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            input = document.getElementById('fileToUpload');;

            file = input.files[0];

            if(file){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

                var shaObj = new jsSHA(reader.result,"BYTES");
                var hash = shaObj.getHash("SHA-512", "HEX");

                xhr.setRequestHeader('Sha-Sha', hash);
            }else{
                alert("First, please select a file to upload.");
                return false;
            }
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete){ },
        success: function() { },
        complete: function(response) { },
        error: function() { }
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <form id="file_up_form" action="upload.php" method="post">
        <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="uploadedfile" />
        <!-- Click on submit to perform AJAX call -->
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"> 
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thx,

But that can't work because javascript is ***** not synchrone and I need to force the synchronisation with the `reader.onload()` callback and then call ajax ... the ajax request will be sent, no matter if the hash is computed or not, if I am inside `.ajaxForm()` it's over, even the `setTimeout(function(){...})` is asynch itself too, so it has no effect the ajax request is sent ... or if I place it in an other place it just crash firefox ...

I have an upload button to trigger the request as you mention of course, and it is the only trigger I have to process the computation of the sha-512 first and then trigger ajax with the form binding.

But what I don't understand is :

why `"startUp('ARandomHash');"` works perfectly inside the `$("#start_up_button").on('click', function() {...});` and `"hash=...; console.log(hash); startUp(hash);"` print the correct hash but ajax is a total fail inside the `reader.onload()` callback ... the event is trigger by the same click event, it has just 2 scope of execution more ...

I don't think I am loosing the submit event with these 2 scope more because the file is uploaded correctly ... it is just the `beforeSend:..., uploadProgress:...`, etc that are not executed.

I think I'll rather try to cast hash, it may be a character encoding problem, it has no sense otherwise, it should fail for the `"startUp('ARandomHash');"` as well ...

But thx, if someone has a better idea =)